# Behat Mink: getAttribute returns WebDriver\Execute Object instead of value

Tags: php, selenium, automated-tests, appium, mink

I use Appium+Selenium2+Behat+Mink, when I try to get attribute by the following code:

```
$id = $this->getSession()->getPage()->find('xpath', $xpath)->getAttribute("id");
```

I get something like this:

```
WebDriver\Execute Object
        (
            [url:protected] => 0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub/session/b1892305-af0b-4bf3-a197-3f58d5ef6954/execute
        )
```

Comment: Possible there is a bug in the version of `mink` or `mink-extension`, I had this issue some time ago and I updated the versions and was fixed.